# Run Access Query from Network Drive Locally

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I have set of Access databases which are stored on a network drive. These databases have their own tables and links to other tables from other databases within this drive. Since queries are run over the network, it takes a while for them to complete. Is there a way I could create an option to copy the required objects to a local folder run the query and then bring the results back to the original database in the network?

Comment: I think this would take too much work to be perfect. Imagine 2 users doing this at the same time, then the user who ran the query later will overwrite the previous person's work. The best thing I would suggest is upgrade to some sort of SQL server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have that problem too.  I copy the source data and my database to my local drive and add two things:

First is a table ("linked table source") that tells where the linked tables are kept.  The 1st row has the location to use when the db is on the network, the 2nd shows where the source data is when I'm on my local PC (in my case, B:)

```
ID  source  path
1   network \\usa0300swg02\sthq\corptax\tax\shared\Common Tables 2016.accdb
2   local   b:\Common Tables 2016.accdb
```

Then I have a VBA function that I have set up in an autoexec macro, to run whenever I load the database:

```
Function relink_tables()

If Left(CurrentDb().Name, 2) = "C:" Or Left(CurrentDb().Name, 2) = "B:" Then
    Source = "local"
    Else: Source = "network"
    End If
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("select * from [linked table source] where source='" & Source & "'")
Source = rs.Fields("path")

For Each R In References
    If InStr(R.Name, "Common Tables") > 0 Then Application.References.Remove R
    Next R
Application.References.AddFromFile Source

x = 0
Set TDefs = CurrentDb().TableDefs
For Each table In TDefs
    If InStr(table.Connect, "Common Tables") = 0 Then GoTo NT
    table.Connect = ";DATABASE=" & Source
    table.RefreshLink
    x = x + 1
NT:
    Next table
Finish:
MsgBox "remapped " & x & " tables"
End Function
```

Notes:

- This also updates references to a code module - you can delete these lines if you don't need them
- You may need to adjust the function for your specific situation - in my case, all my linked tables com from a db called "Common Tables", and I relink everything from that db.  Your exact requirements will probably be different, but this may give you a place to start
- This is also very convenient when I roll over the data base each year - I just update the linked table source (from 2016 to 2017) and re-run the macro

Additional note - as commented by Hynek Bernard above, version control and multi-user access are big considerations.  In my case, I can control who else is using the db when I am using my local copy.  Another option, if you have SharePoint or anything similar, is to use that as the db repository on the network, and use the check-out and check-in features for control.  You still have to get the links right for the location of the downloaded data.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive response. It has given me a good foundation to start with. I will take into consideration what you and Hynek said when it comes to multi-user access.